# How To Add An Instance Of A Model To A List

Tags: c#, oop, model-view-controller

I am working through an MVC Tutorial without a database.

Service Class

```
namespace Domain.Services
{
    public class ThingService
    {
        private List<Thing> _things;
        private List<Thing> Things
        {
            get
            {
                 if (this._things == null)
                 {
                     this._things = new List<Thing>();
                     this._things.Add(new Thing()
                     {
                         ID = 1,
                         Name = "The red thing",
                         Color = "Red",
                         Size = "Small",
                         Length = 55,
                         DateAvailable = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018"),
                         IsActive = true
                     });

                     // Add more things

               }

               return this._things;
            }
        }
```

Controller

```
namespace WWW.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ThingService _thingService;

        public HomeController()
        {
            this._thingService = new ThingService();
        }

        public ActionResult AddThing()
        {
            //add code for a new thing

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I need help adding a new instance of my model to a list (_things? Things?). I have tried the way the Service Class does it and get scope resolution errors.

Can I do this through the _thingService variable available to me in my Controller?

Do I need to add a Method to my Service Class?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `ThingService.Things` is `private`, so it can't be accessed from outside of that class.  Did you mean to make the property `public` instead?

Comment: Then you could do this: `_thingService.Things.Add(new Thing(...))`.

Comment: As mentioned by David that you should set the `Things` to public. Few other points - instead of creating a object of ThingService in constructor, use the `Dependency Injection`. Also, try making your property light weight , it you require an object based on some computation then use function instead of property.

Comment: Thanks to David and user1672994 - I think "private" is part of the exercise. I cannot set to "public".

Comment: HimBromBeere - I have tried your suggestion before posting and the message I get is "ThingService.Things is inaccessible due to its access level.

Comment: My suggestion based on what David mentioned at the beginning. You have to make `Things` public. If this is not possble for you, you need some method - e.g. `Add`- that expects a `Thing`  and adds it to the private list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.  First of all, you're doing too much in your getter (`Things`).  Properties by their very nature should be light-weight data access members.  If you need to do heavy lifting, that's when you consider using a method instead of a property.

With that out of the way, you have a problem: every time someone accesses your list, it's going to be rebuilt, because that's the logic inside your getter; you instantiate and build your list anew every time.

Thirdly, you need to provide access to your property outside your class.  Currently your `Things` property is `private`, so change it to `public` or `internal`.

Here is one simple way to do it:

```
public List<Thing> Things { get; } = new List<Thing>();
```

It's a *public* property (accessible outside your class) that instantiates the list when the class is constructed and provides read-only access to the list, i.e. a *new* list instance cannot be assigned to it.  Here's how you can use it from another class:

```
this._thingService.Things.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property is `private`:

```
private List<Thing> Things
{
    //...
}
```

So, by design, nothing from other classes can access it.  If you make it `public`:

```
public List<Thing> Things
{
    //...
}
```

Then you can access it on any object instance:

```
public ActionResult AddThing()
{
    this._thingService.Things.Add(new Thing());
    return View();
}
```

Covnersely, if you *want* it to be `private`, then you'll need to provide some other way to access it.  For example, a `public` method.  At that point it would be worth reconsidering much of your service's design though because then you'd have a method which just accesses a property and a property with lots of logic in its getter.  This is a bit unbalanced.  Ideally the property would just be accessing the member data (perhaps with minimal logic) and your member initialization logic would be in a constructor or method.

It's worth noting also, however, that any new instance of `ThingService` is going to have an entirely new list of Things (after you first access the property, that is).  So you can add a Thing in your controller, but as soon as you direct to any other page or do anything else you're starting over from scratch again.  For example, if your controller action adds a Thing and then redirects back to the list of Things, that list will again be empty.